# How to keep referral information until user signup

Tags: url, referrals

I would like to add referral program to my website. The user is taken from some other page to my homepage with referral url parameter like:

```
www.example.com?referral=refCode
```

The thing is, the only time I care about the referral code is at the signup page.

```
www.example.com/signup
```

Is there a way to retain the referral code through user journey on my website?

Comment: There are several ways to do this.  I voted to close this question because it needs more focus.  What way have you tried and what challenges have you encountered?

Comment: Nothing and nothing. I have no idea how to do this. Why don't you write the several ways to do this in an answer?

Comment: You can stick it in the database, you can put it in a cookie, you can pass it along in CGI variables. You could put it in local storage. Why don't you try some of those and let us know how it goes

Comment: I know how to stick in the database. I don't know how to put it in a cookie. I don't know what a CGI variable is. That's why I posted this question, to find out, which approach is the best.

Comment: Setting cookies and using t.g.i. variables are very well-documented. There's tons of articles around about them. Why don't you do some reading, take a stab at implementation, and come back to ask a question if you run into a more specific problem

Comment: Instead of conversating with me in the comments, you could have just written the answer and the question would be done. No need to be condescending just because the question style didn't match your preference. If you don't want to help, better not to engage at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue using cookies. Spring Boot provides easy access to cookie operations as described for example in this [article](https://www.websparrow.org/spring/spring-boot-cookies-example).

When an user reaches my home page, I check for the referral parameter and if it exists, I store it in the cookie. I set cookie expiry date for 14 days for example. In the POST controller for the sign-up, I check their cookie and if it contains the referral info, I store it in the DB for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same dilemma recently, and after some thought, I decided to use **cookies**. In my system when user hits `/login`, they are redirected to an external API for social login. By setting cookies from the query on the homepage, I can retrieve them on the backend from the client's cookies. Initially, I thought of using `localStorage`, but it turns out it's impossible to retrieve from it and attach to a query on redirect, partitialy it can be resolved by using a separate login page, but what if I want to redirect a user who hits a protected route or tries to buy something without being logged in? Therefore, cookies are an excellent and straightforward solution in this case.